# Dynamically set a class for menu element with className

Tags: reactjs

I'm stuck on how I would tell my render to only fill the className (I'm using className btw) if I have marked the menu item as highlighted.

[image: menu]

there are two constraints  :

1. Some of the menu items are href/nav links to parts of the app and while clicking on them must apply the style I want to contruct my code in a way that supports the whole component being able to check the adress it's at and decide on if a menu item should have the style or not depending on that also. (As-in support the user "breaking" the app by navigating by hand (typing /item into the adress bar) rather than clicking on the menu item).
2. Some menu items unfold some don't and clicking on a link menu item or unfolding the dropdown are two valid reasons for applying the style and keep in mind the unfolded elements stay unfolded when navigating elsewhere.

So it isn't simply a case of "loosing the style if you weren't the last clicked item".

UPDATE (23/08/2017) :

I've got this from @taylorc93 and it's a step forward :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selected: null;
    };
    this.setSelected = this.setSelected.bind(this);
}

setSelected(row) {
  return () => {
    this.setState({ selected: row });
  }
}

render() {
    var classes = classNames(this.props.className, {
        // if(this.selected)
        'selected': (this.props.selected === this.props.className),
    });
    return (
        <div id="menu">
          <div
            onClick={this.setSelected(1)}
            className={classNames(this.props.className, {
              'selected': this.state.selected === 1,
            })}
          >
            Dropdown 1
          </div>

          <div
            onClick={this.setSelected(1)}
            className={classNames(this.props.className, {
              'selected': this.state.selected === 1,
            })}
          >
            Menu item 2
          </div>

          <div
            onClick={this.setSelected(1)}
            className={classNames(this.props.className, {
              'selected': this.state.selected === 1,
            })}
          >
            Menu item 3
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The issue with thta is it doesn't take into account dropdown behavior (click onece to select a second time to deselect )
So I wordked on it and here's where I'm at :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        tttattta: '',
        selected: null,
        dropDownOne: false,
        dropDownTwo: false,
    };
    this.setSelected = this.setSelected.bind(this);
}

setSelected(row) {
    let tttattta = this.state.tttattta;
    let drop1 = this.state.dropDownOne;
    let drop2 = this.state.dropDownTwo;
    if (row === 1) {
        if (drop1) {
            drop1 = false;
        } else {
            drop1 = true;
        }
    } else if (row === 3) {
        if (drop2) {
            drop2 = false;
        } else {
            drop2 = true;
        }
    } else {
        tttattta = row;
    }
    return () => {
        this.setState({ selected: tttattta,
            dropDownOne: drop1,
            dropDownOne: drop2,
        });
    };
}


render() {
    var classes = classNames(this.props.className, {
        // if(this.selected)
        'selected': (this.props.selected === this.props.className),
    });
    return (
        <div id="menu">
          <div
            onClick={this.setSelected(1)}
            className={classNames(this.props.className, {
              'selected': this.state.selected === 1,
            })}
          >
            Dropdown 1
          </div>

          <div
            onClick={this.setSelected(1)}
            className={classNames(this.props.className, {
              'selected': this.state.selected === 1,
            })}
          >
            Menu item 2
          </div>

          <div
            onClick={this.setSelected(1)}
            className={classNames(this.props.className, {
              'selected': this.state.selected === 1,
            })}
          >
            Menu item 3
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `setSelected` in your render function:

```
<div className={classes} onClick={this.setSelcted(1)}> Menu item 1</div>
```

You need to make `setSelected` return a function that can be invoked when the item is actually clicked:

```
setSelected(row){
  return () => {
    // switch statement here
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

Seems like your trying to find a better way to represent the selected item, which is good :). I'd recommend storing the id of the selected item in your state instead of an array of booleans. Your class would then look like this:

```
class MenuComponent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selected: null;
    };
    this.setSelected = this.setSelected.bind(this);
}

setSelected(row) {
  return () => {
    this.setState({ selected: row });
  }
}

render() {
    var classes = classNames(this.props.className, {
        // if(this.selected)
        'selected': (this.props.selected === this.props.className),
    });
    return (
        <div id="menu">
          <div
            onClick={this.setSelcted(<REPLACE_WITH_ROW_NUM>)}
            className={classNames(this.props.className, {
              'selected': this.state.selected === <REPLACE_WITH_ROW_NUM>,
            })}
          >
            Menu item 1
          </div>
          { /* rest of your menu items here */ }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: about updated answer: wow that's more like it! however we're completely casting asside the notion of differenciating behavior between dropdown and link. this behavior is perfect for the dropdowns (selected when clicked once, deselected when clicked again) not so much for the normal menu items which need to be alone in their possession of the "selected" trait amongst themselves (they can't be several that are highlighted).

Comment: any further ideas to differenciate the two? maybe I simply make two different methods and two different ClassNames? one for dropdowns one for links.

Comment: no actually come to think of it it would have to be the same function but with an extra parameter so that we retain the "deselect all others if dropdown is selected" functionality. Working on it.

Comment: as it  turns out making to separate functions for each foldout plus an extra one like yours for the normal menu items was the best solution. I'm marking you as solution! :)